# n1ql - query an Inner Join for two different queries

Tags: sql, sql++

I'm new to N1QL,  and i'm trying to query an Inner Join for two different queries but I get the exception below. (important to mention that each query was tested separately - and it works just fine)

**THE QUERY I RUN GOES AS FOLLOWS:**

```
SELECT *
FROM(
  (SELECT payload.masterAdId ,
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN payload.active = true
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END) AS numOfActiveversions,
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN payload.active = false
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END)    AS numOfDisabledVersions,
    COUNT(1)AS totalVersions
  FROM mvbucket
  WHERE _identifier    = "adsmartversion"
  AND payload.accountId= 1073741826
  GROUP BY payload.masterAdId limit 1
  )A
JOIN
  (SELECT payload.id AS masterAdId ,
    payload.name     AS masterAdName,
    payload.adAssignmentData.campaignId,
    payload.adAssignmentData.campaignName,
    array_count(payload.adSmartVersionSchema.smartElements[].svKey) AS numberofdynamicelements
  FROM DEFAULT
  WHERE payload.massVersioning             = true
  AND payload.adAssignmentData.campaignId IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY payload.id,
    payload.name,
    payload.adAssignmentData.campaignId,
    payload.adAssignmentData.campaignName,
    array_count((array_star((((default.payload).adSmartVersionSchema).smartElements)).svKey))
  )B
ON keys A.payload.masterAdId);
```

***AND THE EXCEPTION I GET IS:***

```
"errors": [
        {
            "**code": 3000,**
            **"msg": "syntax error - at A"**
        }
```

So it seems to be something with the join structure. Is it possible to do so in N1QL?

Any idea how can I make it work properly?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Currently, the right hand side must be a table / bucket. You can perform the right hand aggregation after the JOIN.

Comment: Thanks!!! will try to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the right hand term of a JOIN must be a table / bucket. You can rewrite your query to perform the right hand aggregation after the JOIN.