# Access SQL: How to retrieve sums of multiple values where user IDs are assigned to multiple positions

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on an Access database for assigning tasks to personnel and tracking task status and workload. A single user ID can be assigned to one of many fields associated with a particular task. In this case, the Task table has fields for "TechReviewerID" "DesignerID" "TechReviewerWorkload" and "DesignerWorkload."

I want one query to return one row for each person, with two summary columns totaling all of the workload assigned to them. So if I'm ID1, I want column 3 to return the sum of "TechReviewerWorkload" in all tasks where "TechReviewerID = 1" and column 4 to return the sum of "DesignerWorkload" in all tasks where "DesignerID = 1."

I have successfully written two separate queries that accomplish this:

```
    SELECT MESPersonnel.MESID, MESPersonnel.PersonnelName, 
    IIF(SUM(DesignerTask.DesignerWorkload) IS NULL, 0, SUM(DesignerTask.DesignerWorkload)) AS 
    TotalDesignerWorkload

    FROM 
    (MESPersonnel LEFT OUTER JOIN Task AS DesignerTask ON (MESPersonnel.MESID = 
    DesignerTask.DesignerID 
    AND DesignerTask.DueDate < CDATE('2020-07-30') AND DesignerTask.DueDate > CDATE ('2020-05-01')))
        
        WHERE MESPersonnel.PositionID = 1
            GROUP BY MESPersonnel.MESID, MESPersonnel.PersonnelName;
```

This query gives the following table:

```
MESID  PersonnelName  TotalDesignerWorkload
  1    John Doe                40
  2    Dohn Joe                20
```

I can create a near-identical query by replacing all instances of "designer" terms with "tech reviewer" terms.

What I'm looking for is a table like:

```
MESID  PersonnelName  TotalDesignerWorkload  TotalReviewerWorkload  
  1      John Doe              40                     10            
  2      Dohn Joe              20                     20
```

My attempts to combine these two via multiple outer joins resulted in wildly inaccurate sums. [I know how to solve that for items on different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58620925/n1ql-multiple-join-and-sum-query-producing-wrong-output), but I'm not sure how to resolve it when I'm using two items from the same table. Is there some kind of conditional sum I can use in my query that Access supports?

EDIT: Sample Raw Data

```
    Task Table

    TaskID  DesignerID  TechReviewerID  DesignerWorkload  TechReviewerWorkload  DueDate
      1         1              2                40                20             06-20-2020
      2         2              1                20                10             06-20-2020


    MESPersonnel Table

    MESID  PersonnelName
      1       John Doe
      2       Dohn Joe
```

Comment: Edit question to show sample raw data. Appears to be non-normalized structure. Aggregate calc can be performed on multiple fields from same table.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited in example raw data tables. I'm a beginner to a lot of this, so I'm not entirely sure what it would mean for the data to be normalized. I imagine it's just a matter of me not knowing the proper syntax; the issue is that I want to create two aggregates that operate on different conditions and I only know how to apply conditions to my joins via WHERE and ON statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

Query1: TaskUNION
rearranges data to a normalized structure

```
SELECT TaskID, DesignerID AS UID, PersonnelName, DesignerWorkload AS Data, DueDate, "Design" AS Cat FROM MESPersonnel 
    INNER JOIN Task ON MESPersonnel.MESID = Task.DesignerID
UNION SELECT TaskID, TechReviewerID, PersonnelName, TechReviewerWorkload, DueDate, "Tech" FROM MESPersonnel 
    INNER JOIN Task ON MESPersonnel.MESID = Task.TechReviewerID;
```

Query2:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Data) AS SumData
SELECT UID, PersonnelName
FROM TaskUNION
WHERE DueDate BETWEEN #5/1/2020# AND #7/31/2020#
GROUP BY UID, PersonnelName
PIVOT Cat;
```

An alternative would involve 2 simple, filtered aggregate queries on Task table then join those 2 queries to MESPersonnel. Here as all-in-one statement:

```
SELECT MESID, PersonnelName, SumOfDesignerWorkload, SumOfTechReviewerWorkload
FROM (
   SELECT DesignerID, Sum(DesignerWorkload) AS SumOfDesignerWorkload
   FROM Task WHERE DueDate BETWEEN #5/1/2020# AND #7/31/2020# GROUP BY DesignerID) AS SumDesi 
RIGHT JOIN ((
   SELECT TechReviewerID, Sum(TechReviewerWorkload) AS SumOfTechReviewerWorkload
   FROM Task WHERE DueDate BETWEEN #5/1/2020# AND #7/31/2020# GROUP BY TechReviewerID) AS SumTech 
RIGHT JOIN MESPersonnel ON SumTech.TechReviewerID = MESPersonnel.MESID) 
ON SumDesi.DesignerID = MESPersonnel.MESID;
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect, thank you so much! I'll do my best to dissect the syntax and techniques you used here so I can learn how to do this more generally.